# Google Analytics: 'eCommerce / No GA ID / (not set)' converting at 100%

Tags: google-analytics

In my Acquisition report in the "Other" channel, I have 'eCommerce / No GA ID / (not set)' converting at 100%. It more than doubles the revenue than the sum of all the other items in the list. This seems like an error in the tracking code however I cannot find any information on it. It seems to be that the e-commerce tracking wasn't set up properly so it's duplicating. Is this possible and how would I fix it?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: You would have to post your code, specifically the part that you think is erroneous, in order for us to help out. Anything is possibly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem.
Things I've checked are:

- Any changes in the my GA set up around the time 'eCommerce / No GA ID / (not set)' started converting for all conversions. Has this always converted at 100%?

  Take a look at the change history for your GA account under Admin > Account > Change History.

  Any backend changes to my site environment. Have any other users been making changes? Have any plugins been updated etc?

Any of the above would be well worth investigating to narrow the search down.From my perspective I'm wondering whether there's any commonality between us, what are you running your site on? I'm using Wordpress, WooCommerce, and Google Analytics by Yoast with the Google Analytics by Yoast eCommerce tracking addon.

Comment: Another thing you could do is to hop on a live chat with Google from the help menu in Analytics and ask them what's going on. I did that and they found that there was a manual tagging error. Specifically all of the questionable transactions were coming from the city of 'York' and via the browser 'Yoast GA eCommerce Tracker 3.0.5'